# segmentation fault in c language regarding maybe pointer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int     i = 0, num = 0;
    double  j = 0;
    char    *str = NULL;

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        j = i / 3 + i;
        printf("j = %lf \n", j);
    }

    strcpy(str, "Success!");
    printf("%s\n", str); 

    return 0;
}
```

{in this code, I input 3 and i got error like this

j= 0.000000

j= 1.000000

j= 2.000000

signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)

and I want to print
j= 0.000000

j= 1.000000

j= 2.000000

Success!

when i try debug, i got error maybe strcpy(str, "Success!");
what can i do?}

Comment: After `char *str = NULL;` you cannot copy a string to it. It has no memory allocation. One remedy is to skip all that and `puts("Success!");`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to allocate memory to the `str` variable. As soon as you try to access it, for instance in the `strcpy` function, you get a segmentation fault, because you are accessing address NULL, which is 0, which is illegal. The OS catches it and terminates the program with the error you are seeing.

You need to allocate memory for your string. You can do it dinamically, as the code below:

#### Security risk

Please note that I am using a 100 characters array, if you write more than 100 characters you will encounter more errors, similar to the segfault but sometimes trickier to debug, as you may overwrite legal parts of the memory and corrupt your data without knowing it).

There are ways to mitigate this, for instance using `strncpy(str, "Success!",100);` which will write exactly 100 bytes, and stop even if there is no string terminator.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFLEN 100

int main(void)
{
    int     i = 0, num = 0;
    double  j = 0;
    char    *str = NULL;
    
    str = malloc(BUFLEN); // Allocate for 100chars
    memset(str,0,BUFLEN); // Init with zeros, for NULL terminated string

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        j = i / 3 + i;
        printf("j = %lf \n", j);
    }

    strncpy(str, "Success!",BUFLEN);
    printf("%s\n", str); 

    return 0;
}
```

Or statically

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFLEN 100

int main(void)
{
    int     i = 0, num = 0;
    double  j = 0;
    char    str[BUFLEN] = {0};
    

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        j = i / 3 + i;
        printf("j = %lf \n", j);
    }

    strncpy(str, "Success!",BUFLEN);
    printf("%s\n", str); 

    return 0;
}
```

The `malloc` approach gives more flexibility and it is something you will need to learn at some point, but it is very risky if you don't know what is happening. So I can suggest first to understand deeply why your code was not working, and secondly to learn the difference between the stack and the heap.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
char *str = NULL;
...
strcpy(str, "Success!");
```

You're telling `strcpy` to copy the string literal to an *invalid* location (`NULL`), hence the segfault.

You have two choices here:

- You can assign the string literal directly to `str`:

  ```
  str = "Success!";
  ```

  This doesn't *copy* `"Success!` to `str`; instead, it stores the address of the string literal to `str`.  However, if you do this, you should declare `str` as `const char *` so the compiler will yell at you if you try to modify the contents of the string (behavior of writing to string literals is undefined).

  Declare `str` as an *array* of `char` large enough to hold the string plus the terminator, not a pointer:

  ```
  char str[10];
  ...
  strcpy(str, "Success!");
  ```